# react native. the close event of the application

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, redux

On one of the pages of the developed application for ios on react native there is a switch components. When interacting with them, the state of the switches is stored in the Redux storage, but when leaving the page or leaving the application, you need to send the state data to the server. Leaving the page is implemented as follows:

```
props.navigation.addListener('willBlur', async() => {
  props.pushDataOnServer(data, token);
});
```

We add a navigation handler (StackNavigator) for the `willBlur` event, thus we can catch the transition to another page, but what about when closing the application directly from the edit page of the switches? Is there any event for this (e.g. `willExit`, `willClose`)? Or if you know a more effective way, please tell us

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your root component, you can watch for AppState changes.

```
componentDidMount() {
  AppState.addEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  AppState.removeEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
}

handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
  if (nextAppState === 'inactive') {
    console.log('the app is closed');
  }    
}
```

Comment: I want to get state when app is installed but neither in background or foreground.Any help can i get?

Comment: isactive is for when the app is in the background not closed